# cdf is $F_X(x) = 1-(1-x)^k$, is that a "famous" distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The question is the following. I found that the cdf of X is $F_X(x) = 1-(1-x)^k$, where $k$ is a parameter. I was wondering if that is some famous distribution (like the one that has a name, for ex., uniform, Bernoulli, Poisson, etc).

Comment: For $k=1$ it is uniform on $[0,1]$. I don't recognize it otherwise.

Comment: I see why you ask, since it looks similar to Bernoulli, Binomial and Geometric, but it doesn't appear to fit any of these except possibly with very specific parameters that would in effect reduce the term to a constant.  At least, I don't see anything...

Answer (score 3):

It is the distribution function for $\min(U_1,\dots, U_k)$, where $(U_i)$ are i.i.d. uniform $(0,1)$ random variables.